# How can I print a list of all files in a directory with their full path?

Tags: perl, file, directory

What I have:
I have a folder that has many other folders and files within it.  I need to get a list of the paths to all files that are within a folder called l1.  There are many different folders called l1 within my main directory, so I have to search for each l1 folder and return the paths to each file within it.  I have been able to print a list of all the l1 folder locations, but I don't know how to list the files within these locations.  The code I have for finding the locations of all the l1 folders is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
my @folder;
sub wanted {
    if ( -d && $_ eq 'l1' ) {
        push @folder, $File::Find::name;
    }
}
find \&wanted, '/mnt/vbox_share/';
open fp, ">process.txt";
print fp "@folder";
```

What do I need to modify or add to be able to list all file paths that are within the folders I searched for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all that's needed.

- `wanted` ignores everything but files, discarding directories and links
- The full path to the file is in `$File::Find::name` when `wanted` is being executed
- Splitting that on `/` and taking the last but one element `$path[-2]` finds the name of the parent directory
- `print` the full file path if that directory equals `l1`

.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

find( \&wanted, '/path/to/root/dir');

sub wanted {
  return unless -f;
  my @path = split /\//, $File::Find::name;
  print $File::Find::name, "\n" if @path > 1 and $path[-2] eq 'l1';
}
```